# How gsub got its receiver when invoked on command line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm now reading Programming Ruby 1.9&2.0 by Dave Thomas, in which there is the following command line script:

```
$ ruby -pi.bak -e "gsub(/Perl/, 'Ruby')" *.txt
```

I know from this text that -p option places program code within the loop `while; ...; print; end`, and regular expressions match against `$_` within -e scripts. And I found that `gsub` is identical to `$_.gsub` within the -e script. But how gsub got its receiver object, are there any explicit rule describing it?

Comment: There was a question about this not so long ago, but can't find it :/

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "how did `gsub` get its receiver object"? In Ruby, any method (and that includes `gsub`, of course), can "get" its receiver object using the `self` pseudo-variable. There is nothing special about the `-e` option, it just evaluates the code normally as if you had put it in a file.

Comment: @JörgWMittag  But when I invoke `ruby -e 'gsub(/Perl/, Ruby)'` from command line I get `undefined method 'gsub' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`. This time `self` is `main:Object`. But in `ruby -pi.bak -e "gsub(/Perl/, 'Ruby')" *.txt` the receiver of `gsub` is `$_` How did this difference happen?

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit rule describing it because it works like everywhere else in Ruby and has nothing to do with the `-p` flag.
`gsub` gets sent to the `main` object, because it is the default receiver here, and, like you noted, there is no explicit receiver defined.

Ruby has two different gsub methods. The one in [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that you were probably thinking of, and the one in [Kernel](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gsub) that is the answer to your question. `Kernel` gets included by `Object`, `main` is an instance of `Object`.

From the `Kernel#gsub` documentation:

> Equivalent to `$_.gsub...`, except that `$_` will be updated if substitution occurs. Available only when `-p`/`-n` command line option specified.

`$_` is the "The last string read by gets or readline in the current scope."